# Can our movement in the universe be measured through time warping?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

Although we don't realize it, we know that we are moving very quickly in universe. The Earth rotates on its axis at 1,600 km/h, and around the Sun at 100,000 km/h. The star orbits the center of the Milky Way at 850,000 km/h. And our galaxy travels at nearly 2.3 million km/h!

Therefore, at each instant, we have a direction and velocity in relation to the universe. Right?

According to Einstein's theory of relativity, the faster we move in space, the slower our time.

The question I have is: **If we send an atomic clock in the opposite direction that we are moving in the universe, will its time slow down or speed up?** Because in relation to us it is moving faster, but for the Universe it is moving slower than we are.

If that's the case, **can we measure our current speed and direction using just atomic clocks?**

---

EDIT:

I've noticed that this question is basically another situation about the twins paradox.

But I'm still not sure about the measurement issue. I tried to represent a way to measure without depending on accelerations (image below). Can `observer 1` and `observer 2` know exactly the exact moment the other is measuring in order to determine when time on one clock passes faster than the other?

[image: spacemeter]

Comment: Could the person who voted to close please reconsider.  This is clearly not someone discussing non-mainstream physics.  It's someone keen to understand mainstream physics who has some misconceptions that need to be cleared up (and could be here).

Answer (score 3):

You have misunderstood a couple of principles of special relativity, which I will try to clarify for you.

You say 'the faster we move through space, the slower our time' and you interpret that as meaning that space is fixed, and movement is absolute, so that if we are moving our time is somehow slower than the time of someone who is 'stationary in space.' That is wrong.

Firstly, there is no absolute, fixed space. If you are moving relative to me, then I can consider myself to be stationary in space and you to be moving. But equally you can consider yourself to be stationary in space and I to be moving.

Secondly, each of us will appear to be time dilated to the other. That is not because our times 'slow down'- for each of us a second passes at the same rate. Time dilation is the result of the relativity of simultaneity, and arises because a plane of constant time in your frame of reference is a sloping slice through time in mine. If you cannot see why that causes the effect of time dilation, then you should study it until it becomes clear, or ask a separate question about it.